# Append into xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
File file = new File("E:\\file.xml");

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller(); 

jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);     

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

I am able to create file ,but next time want append into xml not create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this java code works to append new node to the xml file......it is based on DOM

```
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
public class writexml1 {

public static void main (String args[]) 
{

File docFile = new File("..\\jquery\\WebContent\\demo\\testing.xml");

Document doc = null;
try 
{
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = db.parse(docFile);
} 
catch (java.io.IOException e) 
{
System.out.println("Can't find the file");
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
System.out.print("Problem parsing the file.");
}

Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

System.out.println("The root element is " + root.getNodeName() + ".\n");

NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();
System.out.print("There are "+children.getLength()+" child elements.\n");
System.out.print("They are: \n");

//Print the file 
for (Node child = root.getFirstChild();child != null;child = child.getNextSibling())
{
if (child.getNodeType() == child.TEXT_NODE)
{
System.out.println("Text: "+child.getNodeValue());
} 
else if (child.getNodeType() == child.ELEMENT_NODE) 
{
System.out.println(child.getNodeName()+" = "+child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
}


//NodeList deleteElement = root.getElementsByTagName("staff");

//Node deleteNode= deleteElement.item(0);

//root.removeChild(deleteNode); 
Element staffElement = doc.createElement("staff");

Node updateText = doc.createTextNode("");
staffElement.appendChild(updateText);
//
Element firstName = doc.createElement("firstname");
String str_firstName="added firstname";
Node firstNameNode = doc.createTextNode(str_firstName);
firstName.appendChild(firstNameNode);

staffElement.appendChild(firstName);

//

Element lastName = doc.createElement("lastname");
String str_lastName="added lastname";
Node lastNameNode = doc.createTextNode(str_lastName);
lastName.appendChild(lastNameNode);

staffElement.appendChild(lastName);


//
Element nickName = doc.createElement("nickname");
String str_nickName="added nickname";
Node nickNameNode = doc.createTextNode(str_nickName);
nickName.appendChild(nickNameNode);

staffElement.appendChild(nickName);


//
Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
String str_salary="$10,000";
Node salaryNode = doc.createTextNode(str_salary);
salary.appendChild(salaryNode);

staffElement.appendChild(salary);


//
root.appendChild(staffElement);

//Node StaffNode=(Node)updateElement;





try{
String outputURL = "..\\jquery\\WebContent\\demo\\testing.xml";

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputURL));

TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();

transformer.transform(source, result);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}   
   }
```

**or**

you should check out the JAXB API. If I understand right, you're xml looks like this:

```
<B>
    <C>11</C>
    <D>21</D>
    <E>31</E>
</B>
```

So code would be:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {
    @XmlElement public String C; // sloppy, probably should be type Integer or something
    @XmlElement public String D;
    @XmlElement public String E;
}

// then, somewhere else in your code you want to serialize...
B b = new B();
b.C = "11";
b.D = "21";
b.E = "31";

JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);

// where w is a Writer instance
c.createMarshaller().marshal(b, w);
```

Answer (score 2):

It wont work this way. You have to create Customers class

```
@XmlRootElement
class Customers {
   @XmlElement(name="customer")
   List<Customer> customers;
}
```

Each time you want to add a Customer you need to unmarshal customers.xml, add the new Customer to Customer list and marshal Customers into customers.xml again.

Comment: For every read/write, you must unmarshal and marshal the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Writer%29) of `marshall` that takes an `Writer`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) thread, create a FileWriter and use it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code `new FileWriter(file, true)` will help you to append the data into already existing file.

Comment: A single liner of irrelated code? This is not an answer at all